# Mock Maven Release

Tags: maven

We have a basic Maven parent POM for all our projects, which is tested with integration tests. However a big part of the customization is for the Maven release plug-in:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <tagBase>https://my-url</tagBase>
        <preparationGoals>clean verify org.acme:my-plugin:my-goal</preparationGoals>
        <completionGoals>org.acme:my-other-plugin:other-goal<completionGoals>
        <resume>false</resume>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried testing it via "release:prepare" and got `Can't release project due to non released dependencies` for the parent POM, which can't even be removed via `-DallowTimestampedSnapshots=true`.

I could test via "release:prepare -DdryRun=true", but that doesn't even test the preparation goals. So the only other way I could think of was to release the POM and then try to release an arbitrary project. So now I'm at version 1.0.14 and have reverted about 50 times, and I don't think that's the right way anymore.

Is there any way to mock a Maven release? Maybe tell him to tag to a local path and have him commit changes there? And he shouldn't deploy to our Nexus either, but I'm at the point where I'm not picky anymore.

Comment: Are the "integration tests" you mention Maven Invoker-based?

Comment: @user944849 Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had a need to do this, and like you I was not interested in actually doing SVN commits or deploys to a remote repo - in my mind that verification was part of other integration tests.  I figured that the `maven-release-plugin` developers would also have a similar need, and indeed they did.  They wrote [mock SCM and wagon providers](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/release/tags/maven-release-2.5.2/maven-release-plugin/src/it/setup/).

You can see the mocks used in the [release plugin POM](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/release/tags/maven-release-2.5.2/maven-release-plugin/pom.xml) profile with id `run-its`.  Note the config uses `setupIncludes` to be sure the mocks are built and installed in the local repo prior to running any actual tests.

The projects themselves need to use the mocks.  Look at one of the [integration tests](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/release/tags/maven-release-2.5.2/maven-release-plugin/src/it/projects/prepare/invoker-basic/pom.xml) to see how to define the `scm` element and add the dependency on the Wagon mock.

I used a [log verification technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31677888/944849) to verify that the appropriate executions were run during the tests.

Note: There are 3 mocks in the setup directory I linked.  I found I only needed to use two of them, the ones with suffix "-dummy."

Answer (score 0):

Modularize your process with profiles. Have a profile that triggers your 'prepare' actions, and a profile that triggers your 'perform' actions, and test *those* instead of or before running the release plugin. Configure the release plugin to do these things by activating the profile.

Comment: I don't want to test `<scm/>`, I want to test the preparation and completion goals.

Comment: Which read their critical information from the scm tag. All prepare does is run an ordinary build and then the scm process.  All release does is scm operations (checkout) followed by mvn -Prelease. No scm, nothing to test.

Comment: Did you read the question? I altered these goals and added a bunch of other plug-ins, and it's crucial to see if they work with each other and are called in the right order ans stuff like that.